# pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError when inserting json, what cause it?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

Since the jsons im trying to insert into the database ain't properly formated as json, I append it to a list and json.loads it, for finally to insert it all into a mongodb document.

What am I doing wrong?

When I try to insert it into the database I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/anon/06bcf743-8b4d-409f-addc-520fc4e19299/PycharmProjects/LiveMe/import_messages_dev.py", line 41, in <module>
    messages.insert_many(json_data)
  File "/media/anon/06bcf743-8b4d-409f-addc-520fc4e19299/PycharmProjects/LiveMe/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 742, in insert_many
    blk.execute(self.write_concern.document, session=session)
  File "/media/anon/06bcf743-8b4d-409f-addc-520fc4e19299/PycharmProjects/LiveMe/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 432, in execute
    return self.execute_command(generator, write_concern, session)
  File "/media/anon/06bcf743-8b4d-409f-addc-520fc4e19299/PycharmProjects/LiveMe/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 329, in execute_command
    raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

My code is as follow:

```
###  DATABASE ####
# Connect to database // login user:password
uri = 'mongodb://testuser:password@ds245687.mlab.com:45687/liveme'
# Set client.
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
# Set database.
db = client.get_database()

# Create collection.
messages = db['messages']

# The url to the live.me replays.
replay_url = "http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?"

userid = 895324164037541888

# Parsing the urls for replays and profile with the userid.
url2 = replay_url + urllib.parse.urlencode({'userid': userid}) + '&page_size=1000'

# Printing urls for own validation.
print(f"Replay url: {url2}\n")

raw_replay_data = requests.get(url2).json()

# Insert messages to database.
for i in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    url3 = i['msgfile']
    raw_message_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url3)
    json_data = []
    for line in raw_message_data:
        json_data.append(json.loads(line))
        messages.insert_many(json_data)
        print(json_data)
```

**Update for more information to answer**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/anon/06bcf743-8b4d-409f-addc-520fc4e19299/PycharmProjects/LiveMe/import_messages_dev.py", line 51, in <module>
    msgfiles = [json.loads(line) for line in msgfile.iter_lines()]
  File "/media/anon/06bcf743-8b4d-409f-addc-520fc4e19299/PycharmProjects/LiveMe/import_messages_dev.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    msgfiles = [json.loads(line) for line in msgfile.iter_lines()]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

** Second update for more information to answer **

The thing is, that it is still inserting a single line into one document.
In ex. http://live.ksmobile.net/live/getreplayvideos?userid=895324164037541888&page_size=1000 
contain 120 "replays" with each their "msgfile".

I want all the content to be 1 "msgfile" == 1 mongodb document.
So iterate through all the "msgfile"'s from the above link and insert ALL content from 1 "msgfile" into 1 document.

"msgfile": "http://s.live.ksmobile.net/cheetahlive/86/9e/15207987261090823831/15207987261090823831.json"

"msgfile": "http://s.live.ksmobile.net/cheetahlive/ae/41/15206244909238491194/15206244909238491194.json",

ect..

These 120 "msgfile"s when inserted now line by line generates 65.113 documents instead of 120 documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second loop builds up a least all the while inserting each build up to the messages collection.

Build up the list of messages to be inserted then insert them. *e.g.*

Sample 1.

```
...
for info in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    msgfile_url = info['msgfile']
    msgfile = requests.get(msgfile_url)
    msgfiles = [json.loads(line) for line in msgfile.iter_lines() if line.strip()]

    messages.insert_many(msgfiles)
```

Sample 2.

You can also build up `msgfiles` and then insert it at the end of the loop.

```
msgfiles = []
for info in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    msgfile_url = info['msgfile']
    msgfile = requests.get(msgfile_url)
    msgfiles.extend([json.loads(line) for line in msgfile.iter_lines() if line.strip()])
message.insert_many(msgfiles)
```

Sample 3.

For when you run into errors with MongoDb balking when inserting rather large amount of data, you can thread your requests. *e.g.*

```
import json
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
...
q = Queue()
...

def consumer():
    while True:
        msgfiles = q.get()
        messages.insert_many(msgfiles)
        q.task_done()

...
for _ in range(6):
    t = Thread(target=consumer)
    t.start()

for info in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    msgfile_url = info['msgfile']
    msgfile = requests.get(msgfile_url)
    msgfiles = [json.loads(line) for line in msgfile.iter_lines() if line.strip()]

    q.put(msgfiles)

q.join()
```

**EDIT**

Insert message files at a video info URL as a single document.

Sample 1.

```
for info in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    msgfile_url = info['msgfile']
    msgfile = requests.get(msgfile_url)
    msgfiles = [json.loads(line) for line in msgfile.iter_lines() if line.strip()]
    document = {'url': msgfile_url, 'data': msgfiles}
    messages.insert_one(document)
```

Sample 2.

```
msgfiles = []
for info in raw_replay_data['data']['video_info']:
    msgfile_url = info['msgfile']
    msgfile = requests.get(msgfile_url)
    document = {
        'url': msgfile_url,
        'data': [json.loads(line) for line in msgfile.iter_lines() if line.strip()]
    }
    msgfiles.append(document)
message.insert_many(msgfiles)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the 3 approaches. There's something for me to go in depth with!!! All 3 approaches give me the same error tho. I have updated my original post with the error, if you kindly can assist me once more.

Comment: Filter out blank lines from the returned content.

Comment: The thing is, that it is still inserting a single line into one document. What should be 120 documents in this case, become 65.113 documents. I have updated the original question again with more information for better readability. :)

Comment: What did you try? For your new use case, there is `pymongo.collection.insert_one`. You will need to massage your data to a dictionary to work this. Keying your data with `msgfile_url` as written in my example is one way to go.